# is there any way to store 'date' value to the Realtime firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase

**JavaScript**

1. This is my JavaScript code  I want to store Date value to
   firebase but some reason it is storing only 4 values from the form
   whereas I wanted to store 6
2. did I choose a wrong backend language for the database ?
3. This is my JavaScript code  I want to store Date value to
   firebase but some reason it is storing only 4 values from the form
   whereas I wanted to store 6
4. did I choose a wrong backend language for the database ?
5. This is my JavaScript code  I want to store Date value to
   firebase but some reason it is storing only 4 values from the form
   whereas I wanted to store 6
6. did I choose a wrong backend language for the database ?
7. This is my JavaScript code  I want to store Date value to
   firebase but some reason it is storing only 4 values from the form
   whereas I wanted to store 6
8. did I choose a wrong backend language for the database ?

   ```
   var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyBM93QmsJlOUL8dfyiQdAIUxIyQvIdbuW4",
     authDomain: "form-a8c0e.firebaseapp.com",
     projectId: "form-a8c0e",
     storageBucket: "form-a8c0e.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "839286832311",
     appId: "1:839286832311:web:3afbc112b987a15f22a132",
   };
   // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

   // Reference messages collection
   var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");

   // Listen for form submit
   document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

   // Submit form
   function submitForm(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // Get values
     var name = getInputVal("name");
     var email = getInputVal("email");
     var phone = getInputVal("phone");
     var message = getInputVal("message");
     var message = getInputVal("haircut");
     var message = getInputVal("haircutTypes");

     // Save message
     saveMessage(name, email, phone, message, haircut, haircutTypes);

     // Show alert
     document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "block";

     // Hide alert after 3 seconds
     setTimeout(function () {
       document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "none";
     }, 2500);

     // Clear form
     document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
   }

   // Function to get get form values
   function getInputVal(id) {
     return document.getElementById(id).value;
   }

   // Save message to firebase
   function saveMessage(name, email, phone, message, haircut, haircutTypes) {
     var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
     newMessageRef.set({
       name: name,
       email: email,
       phone: phone,
       message: message,
       haircut: haircut,
       haircutTypes: haircutTypes,
     });
   }
   ```

what it is doing is storing data of haircuttype to message

Comment: sorry my friends I had to repeat those line above because otherwise error was keep coming up. I hope you will understand this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Make sure you configure the security rules or your data might get hacked

Comment: Ok thank you i will do that when I will put live #fxnoob